# Lebesgue integration by substitution mistake

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, substitution

In my notes I have the following two results. I recognise the latter from normal integration by substitution but it the first I don’t know where the derivative $|\varphi’(x)|$ has gone.

Why does the derivative of the substitution not appear in the first result? [image]

[image]

Comment: Indeed there are no derivatives involved in the first formula. Its a more general formula that dosen't require differentiability of $\varphi$. It is very useful nonetheless, for example in probability when integrating random variables with respect to their distribution (image measure ).

Comment: The derivative is hiding in the connection formula between $\mu$ and $\nu$. If you imagined the differentials $d\mu$ and $d\nu$ and lived on $\mathbb{R}$, $\varphi'$ would pop right out after a little massaging.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a very simple formula just based on the definition of $\mu$ in terms of $\phi$ and $\nu$ (and simple function approximation). No smoothness and derivatives are involved in it.